# Visual Studio 2022 File not found in current source file's directory or in build system paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio, imgui

For some reason, the `Calculator.h` is not being seen by the Visual studio, evert time I build the solution it keep throwing same error `E1696  cannot open source file "Calculator.h"` and `C1083  Cannot open include file: 'Calculator.h': No such file or directory`.

I tried to clean and rebuild the solution, that as well didn't work. But in same directory main.cpp was able to see and reach `Application.h` file.
I tried to 'Add existing items' option as well, that also did not work.

What would be the possible cause of this? PFB file structure.

Solution Directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nT3H.png)

All files:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB7h9.png)

File explorer:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYeGe.png)

Code where file is included:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0grfI.png)

Here it is not being detected:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aMQs.png)

Comment: Clearly something weird going on. Why does your 'All files' listing contain duplicate file names? That's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some apparent duplicates which seems to be shortcuts. I'd suggest to delete the shortcuts from your project.

[image]

Comment: Those are files which are part of old Release, the one you see with red dot.

Comment: @Zoro As a matter of fact, I don't need these explanations. I only pointed the anomalies explicitly, and what exactly you should do to solve the problem. So, where did that come from, how to handle it, it is irrelevant, and now now that's your part to decide. If you still have questions, just ask.